# CSS : background-clipping regarding to above elements?

Tags: css, background, gradient, mask, clip

I have this layout on my HTML-page :
[page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYbOX.jpg)

It's a form with checkboxes (which are hidden) and the labels are styled to look like buttons (white border and transparent background to show the gradient below). The gradient part is the container.

Now what I would like to achieve is to show the gradient background only below the buttons so that the parts between the buttons remains white.

See the example here : [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nByqV.jpg) (and worship my Photoshop skills)

I tried to figure out a solution but I ended up with nothing. If some of you guys could help me out, I would really appreciate it :)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Maybe you can show us your thoughts about a solution and we can try to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create multiple small round boxes with no `background` and large `box-shadow` values.
- Excess shadow on these boxes will be clipped by `overflow: hidden` on their respective parents.
- Apply gradient background on the outermost parent.

Here is a working demo:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(orange, yellow) no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
}
.list {
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list li {
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.list .box {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #fff;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <div class="box">Immobilier</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">Travaux</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">Finance</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">Evenementiel</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">Juridique</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">Communication</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">Recrutement</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```